# Symfony2: JMSAop intercepting only services

Tags: symfony, service, aop

I use JMS Aop Bundle to intercept call to methods of my bundles. Currently, my Pointcut is:

```
public function matchesClass(\ReflectionClass $class)
{
    return $class->isSubclassOf('AbstractService');
}

public function matchesMethod(\ReflectionMethod $method)
{
    return true;
}
```

This works great with 'real' services (that are declared as normal service), but not with other like Type, Listener, etc. whereas they also inherit from AbstractService. Is it possible to also catch the calls to these classes ?